# Can I disable monitor dimming/screen saver when playing videos? VLC/Web(HTML5/Flash/Silverlight/QuickTime)

Tags: video, power-management, screensaver

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I stop the screensaver from turning on when I watching online videos?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/144621/how-do-i-stop-the-screensaver-from-turning-on-when-i-watching-online-videos)

Is it possble to disable Monitor dimming/Screensaver only on video playback? For me, videos will be mainly Desktop via VLC or Web via FireFox/Chrome (HTML5/Flash/Silverlight/Quicktime)